# When Visual Studio trial is expired, can I buy and use a valid license key for the current installation?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, license-key

This is a question on Visual Studio 2010 license key.

- If I install the Visual Studio 2010
  Professional edition for trial, once
  it is expired, can I convert this
  trial to "full" using a purchased
  license key? or...
- do I need to buy and
  download a new Visual Studio 2010
  Professional fullname?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can as the Trial and Official ISO's are the same, except that some features are disabled in the trial.

When you'll buy a key, you'll be able to modify (via add/remove apps in windows) VS2010 to change the licence key to the one you just bought.

Comment: It's easier to do it from "Help" > Register Product than use Change Programs or Features.

Comment: Oh well, I missed that one :P Good point ;)